# Hide other recipients while sending mail phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I know this question is asked many times. I have few queries regarding sending mail to multiple recipients.

1. I have an array with multiple email addresses  `$mail_address[]`. I don't want to make each recipients to know the other recipients address. So I think I cannot use `addAddress()` method. So can I use `AddBCC()` method  without `addAddress()` method if I am sending mail to all recipients at once.
2. If the above solution is not possible, I need to add each recipients inside the `foreach loop` and will use `addAddress()` method. But each time whole code should run which I fear it can affect the optimization of my system.

So what can be a better solution for me.

Comment: try using a loop to send email

Comment: @Poria so using loop will not affect performance if many reciever mals are there???

Comment: that is a different question already answered here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117973/bulk-mailing-performance-sending-method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send same email layout after processing lots of data then you should first process data once and should make email layout and store in one variable.

After that you can write foreach loop to send an email to individual which wont affect your execution time.

```
//Process all data and make layout variable with value.

$layout = '<email template>';

foreach($mail_address as $mail_item) {
//Send an email to $mail_item with $layout variable.
}
```